# IBOutlet nil in DetailViewController of a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When using a SplitViewController, an image connected via an IBOutlet in my DetailViewController is nil.

I'm using a protocol to communicate between the MasterViewController and the DetailViewController

```
protocol EventSelectedDelegate: class {
    func eventSelected(event: Event)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "eventDetailsSegue" {

        let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

        let selectedIndex = self.eventTableView!.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
        let event = self.events[selectedIndex!.row]

        self.delegate = controller
        self.delegate?.eventSelected(event)

        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    }
}
```

And implementing the method in the DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, EventSelectedDelegate {

    private var event : Event?
    @IBOutlet weak var eventImage: UIImageView!

    func eventSelected(event: Event) {
        self.event = event
        self.configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        if let event = self.event {
            self.title = event.name

            if let eventImage = self.eventImage {
                eventImage.image = event.image    // <--- Never reached.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example SplitViewController works fine, where a UILabel is connected via a IBOutlet.

The only difference I can tell between the example code and my code, is that I have a separate storyboard for the UISplitViewController section, which I am loading in my AppDelegate.swift file

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyBundle", bundle: NSBundle(identifier: "com.example.MyBundle"))
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

I'm using XCode 7, and Swift 2. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the line of unwrapping an optional : if let eventImage = self.eventImage,  I have one question. Have u assigned the eventImage property of the delegate before trying to unwrap ??

Comment: I will add more of the class, was trying to keep the code short with just snippets. eventImage is defined in in the DetailViewController class.

Comment: Sure thanks. Are you sure that self.eventImage is not nil ? Did u try to log it out in console ? I believe the unwrapping is resulting in a nil. Thats why the control never reaches the code in the "if" block.

Comment: I have stepped into the configure function, and self.eventImage is indeed nil. I only added the unwrapping after it crashed.

Comment: Yeah @Jeremy self.eventImage will be nil coz it wasn't initialised before. And you have added unwrapping to the property which wasn't initialised before so it'll always be nil and would not enter the if block. Look into the below answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Even if I have connected the eventImage IBOutlet to an UIImageView in my storyboard? If I do this without the SplitViewController it works fine. I did think it's to do with how the DetailViewController gets instantiated, but I don't know where that happens.

Comment: Yeah that is right. Do you have separate VC for detail VC of Split VC. If so you need to instantiate it and assign it. Coz, the image view of detailVC is nil which is an implicitly unwrapped optional, which will get initialised when the VC is created from story board. Pls check updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I could think is that, your self.eventImage is nil and it is an implicitly unwrapped optional, the property self.eventImage is initialised when your View Controller from story board is initialised.

If you have a different View Controller in the Story board for the Detail VC please try to create an object for it and assign it to detail VC and try. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Will try this and look into where the storyboard is initialised.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was as you said, I was calling `self.configure()` before the DetailViewController was initialised. And all I should have done is set the local copy of event, and call `self.configure()` in `viewWillAppear()`.